# Count(*) in Group By - Returns 1, instead of '0'

Tags: oracle, group-by, count

I am using the below oracle query to get the count of rows.

```
SELECT T.ID,T.NAME,COUNT(*) AS NO_OF_STUDENTS FROM STUDENT S RIGHT JOIN 
TEACHER T ON S.TEACHER_ID = T.ID
GROUP BY T.ID,T.NAME ORDER BY T.ID
```

Actual Result Should be:

```
TEACHER 1 - 10 STUDENTS   
TEACHER 2 - 5 STUDENTS   
TEACHER 3 - 0 STUDENT
```

The Result what i am getting is:

```
TEACHER 1 - 10 STUDENTS   
TEACHER 2 - 5 STUDENTS   
TEACHER 3 - 1 STUDENT
```

Since TEACHER 3 is not having any student, the result should be 0 Student. But i am getting the result as 1 Student.

Comment: You want `count(rpz.id)`

Comment: And you probably want the select list and group-by to use `cs.id` so you can see what you are getting zero for?

Comment: I should get the Count()  from TABLE1. In that case, instead of Count(), shall i use Count(cs.id) ?

Comment: The count from table1 must be non-zero, or there would be no row in the result set. You can get zero by counting matches in table2 because of the left outer join. Or is your outer join the wrong way around? Please edit your question to include sample data and expected results.

Comment: I have edited my question with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to count a specific column (not use `*`, which includes nulls) in the table being outer joined to - since that is the one that might not have matching data. So:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.NAME, COUNT(S.ID) AS NO_OF_STUDENTS
FROM STUDENT S
RIGHT JOIN TEACHER T ON S.TEACHER_ID = T.ID
GROUP BY T.ID, T.NAME
ORDER BY T.ID
```

The only difference is `COUNT(S.ID)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Simple demo with made-up data provided via CTEs:

```
with teacher (id, name) as (
  select 1, 'Teacher 1' from dual
  union all select 2, 'Teacher 2' from dual
  union all select 3, 'Teacher 3' from dual
),
student (id, teacher_id) as (
  select level, 1 from dual connect by level <= 10
  union all
  select level + 10, 2 from dual connect by level <= 5
)  
SELECT T.ID, T.NAME, COUNT(S.ID) AS NO_OF_STUDENTS
FROM STUDENT S
RIGHT JOIN TEACHER T ON S.TEACHER_ID = T.ID
GROUP BY T.ID, T.NAME
ORDER BY T.ID;

        ID NAME      NO_OF_STUDENTS
---------- --------- --------------
         1 Teacher 1             10
         2 Teacher 2              5
         3 Teacher 3              0
```

You could also do this as a left join, which I find more intuitive:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.NAME, COUNT(S.ID) AS NO_OF_STUDENTS
FROM TEACHER T
LEFT JOIN STUDENT S ON S.TEACHER_ID = T.ID
GROUP BY T.ID, T.NAME
ORDER BY T.ID
```

which gets the same result.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks a lot. Whatever you have mentioned was working fine. Also, i have taken you suggestion of using Left Join. Once again Thanks.